# ZK methode call when enter pressed

Tags: textbox, onchange, zk

I have a textbox in zk. If I pressed tab call the onChanged event. 
What need I do for call onChange event when press enter? Currently when I press enter not happens anything at all.

```
<textbox id="inputWord" width="200px" apply="com.wb.controlers.WBControler" />
```

WBControler.java (Extends GenericForwardComposer)

```
public void onChange$inputWord(Event event) throws Exception {
        Component c = event.getTarget();
        if (c instanceof Textbox) {
            wordTextbox = (Textbox)c;
        }
        if (wordTextbox != null) {
          // do something
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key fires the `onOK` event in ZK (both 'O' and 'K' are uppercase).

The ZK documentation discusses the details [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Keystroke_Handling).

Using a `GenericForwardComposer` you would define an event listener like so:

```
public void onOK$inputWord(Event event) {
    // do something
}
```

Using a `SelectorComposer` (introduced in ZK 6.0) you would define your event listener like so:

```
@Listen(Events.ON_OK + " = #inputWord")
public void onEnterPressed(Event event) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to execute a single bit of code for multiple events, have a look into [Event Forwarding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Forwarding). For example..

```
// in your controller
@Listen("onQuery = #inputWord")
public void onQuery(Event event) {
    // do something
}

// in your zul file
<texbox id="inputWord" forward="onOK=onQuery, onChange=onQuery" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[

    $( window ).load(function() { 
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('textboxLogin')[0]!=null){
    document.getElementsByClassName('textboxLogin')[0].addEventListener('keyup',
    onKeyUpAcces, false); }


    if(document.getElementsByClassName('textboxLogin')[1]!=null){
        document.getElementsByClassName('textboxLogin')[1].addEventListener('keyup',
        onKeyUpAcces, false); }

    });


    function onKeyUpAcces(e) {
        console.log('onkeyUp');
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if(document.getElementById('f')!=null){
                document.getElementById('f').submit();
            }
        }
    }

    ]]>
</script>
```